# Multiple Values Request Parsing coming for select multiple

Tags: python, flask

*hello I have a selector multiple and I am trying to get the list of values*

**on html (only important parts)**

```
        <form
          action="{{ url_for('users.create') }}"
          method="POST"
          enctype="multipart/form-data"
          class="form-horizontal"
          id="user_detail_form">
          <select multiple id="zone" class="selectpicker form-control custom" data-actions-box="true" name="zone" style="border-radius: 6px;"/>
                  {% for zone in zones %}
                  <option value="{{ zone }} {% if form.data.zone == zone %} selected {% endif %}"> {{ zone }} </option>
                  {% endfor %}
                  </select>
        <button type="submit" form="user_detail_form" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-right">
          <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Create
        </button>
```

**on python Flask:**

```
        user = reqparse.RequestParser()
        user.add_argument('zone', required=False, action='split') #or append
        args = parsers.user.parse_args()
```

and I only get a list with first value ['Ouest ']
I know I did not put all the code, maybe you have an idea if you need more precisions don't hesitate.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

for Flask try using request object (from flask import request)

POST: values = request.form.getlist('zone')

GET: values = request.args.getlist('zone')